# Swift: Chain multiple network request, Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a question about chain more network requests (Alamofire) but the number of that requests can be sometimes 4 sometimes 9 etc, it depends on target configurations.
I have one dashboard viewcontroller and that VC has 4-9 embedded VC's, everyone must fetch some data from API and that is the issue, all of them try to fetch "in the same time" but a lot of them fails, randomly.

I use semaphore for this issue but sometimes request failed, not sure why. I think one request blocks another or something like that.

For example this I have:

```
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
        dispatchQueue.async {
        if MDUtilites.isMediaPresent() {
                let _ = self.fetchMediaList()
                self.semaphore.wait()
                
            }
}
```

and I have about 10 block of codes like this and func is:

```
func fetchMediaList() {
    MDApiManager.sharedInstance.fetchMediaList { (dict, status) in
        switch (status) {
        case .failed(let code, _, let description):
            print("failed:")
            print(code)
            print(description)
            self.semaphore.signal()
        case .success(_, _ , _):
            print("success")
            
            if let data = dict,
                let list = data.parseWith(type: MediaBase.self)?.list {
                self.newMedia = list
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: MEDIA_UPDATE), object: nil)
                //                    self.mediaListSections = list
                //                    self.getCategories(data: list)
            }
            self.semaphore.signal()
        case .unknown:
            print("DEBUG: unknown fetchMediaList")
            self.fetchMediaList()
        //                self.semaphore.signal()
        case .error(let aError):
            print(aError)
            self.semaphore.signal()
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help to solve this issue with more requests at the same time, Semaphore sometimes works sometimes not.

It was some bug in code Semaphore works as it should

Comment: Using semaphore is usually a bad idea. You could have use a DispatchGroup to handle the end of multiple concurrent requests. with the notify, it's easier.

Comment: Does your API call are concurrent or serial ?? I mean APIs are dependent on each other or they will be execute independently.

Comment: no APIs are not dependent

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `semaphore` for your  requests . Since your request are  executed asynchronously / independent of one another , depending on type of request it takes time for execution. Each of your `controller` fetch this request when it loaded into memory . Fetch them in `ViewDidLoad()` . Make sure you are adding your multiple `controllers` correctly into your `parent` `controller`.

Comment: That is why how was in begin when it was 3-4 embedded VC's, but now when I have 7-9 API requests it is a problem, sometimes some of them just enter in failed state like if it is backend issue, but it is not. I put all of this in one singleton class so I can use semaphore but no luck

Comment: Can you try hit api using url session for each hit instead of `Alomfire` . My network helper works fine even this 10 or 15 request at the same time . Don't try singleton class in this.